# Change to beginning of line excluding spaces

Tags: vim

Is it possible to change to the beginning of the line excluding the spaces?

So, what I would like to do is `0wC` with a single command since I do it so often. There is `S` and `cc` but those delete the beginning spaces. I could override `S` but I was hoping there was something built in. E.g.,

Before:

```
    My line starts he{cursor}re.
```

After:

```
    {cursor}
```

Comment: If you have `autoindent` on, both `cc` and `S` *do* preserve the indentation. Though obviously it affects other things, some of which you may not want...

Comment: OK, yeah, I like the code to be clean and `autoindent` can mess that up. Nice to know though that is is built in though - just not for me I guess. I guess I'll just override it. Not ideal but whatever.

Comment: I'd suggest using `^C` instead of `0wC`, so that it will still work on lines without any whitespace at the beginning.

Comment: `autoindent` only copies indent from the current line when starting a new one. How can that mess up code? (Maybe you want `smartindent` or a properly configured `cindent` as well?)